# Deployment with e(fx)clipse - Build Error

Tags: deployment, ant, javafx, build.xml

I am trying to deploy a stand-alone build of my JavaFx application and have followed the tutorial from [Code.Makery](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-2-tutorial/part7/).

I am getting this error:

> init-fx-tasks:
>     [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
>   do-deploy:
>        [copy] Copying 1 file to C:_source\MasterGuildWarsCode\build\dist\libs
>
> BUILD FAILED C:_source\MasterGuildWarsCode\build\build.xml:91:
>   C:_source\MasterGuildWarsCode\resources does not exist.
>
> Total time: 2 seconds

This is the section of my build.xml file that seems to be the problem:

```
<mkdir dir="dist/resources" />
<copy todir="dist/resources" >
    <fileset dir="../resources" />
</copy>

<mkdir dir="package" />

<!-- Icons only for Windows -->
<mkdir dir="package/windows" />
<copy todir="package/windows">
    <fileset dir="..">
        <include name="AXI.ico" />
        <include name="AXI.bmp" />
    </fileset>
</copy>

<!-- Icons only for MacOS -->
<mkdir dir="package/macosx" />
<copy todir="package/macosx">
    <fileset dir="..">
        <include name="AXI.icns" />
    </fileset>
</copy> 

<fx:resources id="appRes">
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="MasterGuildWarsCode.jar"/>
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="resources/**"/>
</fx:resources>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this tutorial instead: [Efxclipse/Tutorials/AddingE(fx)clipse to eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/AddingE(fx)clipse_to_eclipse). I've tested it and works perfectly.

Make sure you follow all the steps. Specially this one: "Configure eclipse to use a JDK not a JRE". This will guarantee that you won't have any trouble when you ant build and run your app.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I started by making a decent answer with print screens and stuff, but then my answer got blocked because I had too much images for my reputation... I got frustrated and basically just submit the first paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that tutorial (Step 4), there is a section like this in the build.xml:

```
<path id="fxant">
  <filelist>
    <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
    <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
    <file name="${basedir}"/>
  </filelist>
</path>
```

Do those jars exist at the specified paths in the JDK that Ant executes with?

A very similar question was asked here: [JAVAFx Build Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24840414/127035), with suggestion to change from

```
<file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
```

to

```
<file name="${java.home}\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar"/>
```

I don't know whether that is correct or not, but I do suggest checking those paths.