# JavaFx build.xml Failed

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, ant

I created a javafx project and exported it as a runnable jar. Some javafx classes did not get packaged with the external jars so I decided to export it using ant. I generated the build.xml file using build.fxbuild but when I right click xml -> Run As -> Ant Build,  I receive this error:

```
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/lib/ant-javafx.jar!/com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml:13: typedef A class needed 
by class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.Application cannot be found: 
org/apache/tools/ant/types/DataTypeusing the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\lib\ant-javafx.jar]
```

Comment: Check the path of jars in your build.xml, refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840414/javafx-build-failed

Comment: When I right click build.xml -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path, the JRE and JDK are both present. Likewise under Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration -> JRE, Separate JRE is selcted and jdk1.8.0 is selected. I am still receiving error